# Mail will not send in HTML

Tags: html, email, wp-mail, html-email

Okay, I've got the following issue. I'm trying to send a mail in HTML format. I made a class that returns an HTML string, and that works great.

When I pass that html-mail as $message in my function, works also. But it will not send as html, but plain text.

Now I've tried the following things:

1)
`$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`

2)
`$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

3)
`$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";`

4)
`function wpse27856_set_content_type(){
      return "text/html";
   }
   add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );`

What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
  add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

    $to = 'sendto@example.com';
    $subject = 'The subject';
    $body = 'The email body content';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body , $headers);

    // Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

    function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
        return 'text/html';
    }
```

Comment: Already tried that one ;) But thanks for your answer. I use the standard PHP mail function now, and that does work...

Comment: Using this filter always works for me.  I don't need the extra Content-Type header.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use the `wp_mail`-function, nor the php `mail`-function.
Both of them don't give you much control over your email. If you want to send HTML emails it's a good idea to send a plain text mail with it, so that users that are unable to read HTML emails can read your message too.

Have a look on `phpmailer` that's a very good email sending class which gives you a lot of control over the email. You can add plain text to an HTML email, set a sender name instead of just having your email address and so on.